# Making a delay without try/catch, or having it in one function

Tags: java, delay

I want to make my simple applet as least cluttered as possible. Currently all my delays are like

```
try
{
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
}
catch(InterruptedException e)
{
}
```

but its really cluttered. I want to have some sort of function, such as

```
try
{
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(Delay);
}
catch(InterruptedException e)
{
}
```

then have it get called like this somehow

```
delay(3)
```

Or, just get rid of the `try/catch` statement in general. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a method that swallows the try/catch.

```
public void timeDelay(long t) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(t);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
}
```

Anytime you want to sleep, call the method.

```
public void myMethod() {
    someCodeHere();
    timeDelay(2000);
    moreCodeHere();
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you! I have one more question, is there any way to make that as a seperate class, and have it call back to that class? I just started, so my questions may sound really stupid

Comment: @Hello234: this must be a method, but a method can be in whatever class you wish to put it in. If you need it to be in a utility class, then create one. You'd then probably want to make the method static.

Comment: Please make sure to at least log the `InterruptedException` somewhere. Just eating it is not a good idea.